# Creating a Rails Engine: How to separate resque workers by application?

Tags: resque, rails-engines

I'm creating a Rails Engine that has some background workers using resque. The problem is that if I have two applications running locally, using this engine, any worker I have running will execute the tasks for both apps.

I want to isolate these applications. Any idea where to start?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to reference some unique identifier from wherever you are executing the `Resque.enqueue` in the engine:

```
Resque.enqueue "#{Rails.application.class.parent_name}_engine_jobs", EngineJob
```

Then you can reference these application-specific queue names from the worker(s).